# $\ \sqrt{x+39}-\sqrt{x+7}=4 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

So I tried to solve this problem for x

$\ \sqrt{x+39}-\sqrt{x+7}=4 $

I multiplied both sides ($\ \sqrt{m}\cdot\sqrt{n}=\sqrt{mn} $)

$\ (\sqrt{x+39}-\sqrt{x+7})^2=16 $

$\ (x+39)-2(x^2+46x+273)-(x+7) $

$\ 0x+32+(-2x^2-92x-546) $

$\ -2x^2-92x-514 $

divide the 2 out

$\ x^2+46x+257=-8 $

$\ x^2+46x+265=0 $

Use the quadratic formula (or scientific calculator) and the answers are -6.752 and -39.248. I know the answer is exactly -3. What went wrong?

Comment: When you square the difference of the two radicals, your middle term is incorrect.

Comment: @WebMatser, Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/400403/solve-sqrtx4-sqrtx1-1-for-x

Comment: ah I really tried looking for related posts first, but I didn't see that one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made two mistakes when squaring. The correct equation is
$$(x + 39) - 2\sqrt{(x+39)(x+7)} + (x + 7) = 16$$
This can be rearranged as
$$2x + 30 = 2\sqrt{(x+39)(x+7)}$$
Dividing by 2:
$$x + 15 = \sqrt{(x+39)(x+7)}$$
Square again
$$x^2 + 30x + 225  = (x+39)(x + 7)$$
$$= x^2 + 46x + 273$$
So your equation is the same as
$$30x + 225 = 46x + 273$$
So $16x = -48$ and therefore $x = -3$.
When squaring equations always plug in your answer to make sure it's the actual solution. And in this case it is.

Comment: What was the second mistake I made? Just wondering

Comment: you have $-(x+7)$ on the right instead of $x + 7$

Answer (score 9):

One can square twice. I prefer to invert and obtain
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+39}-\sqrt{x+7}}=\frac{1}{4},$$
and then by rationalizing the denominator get
$$\frac{\sqrt{x+39}+\sqrt{x+7}}{32}=\frac{1}{4},$$
or equivalently 
$$\sqrt{x+39}+\sqrt{x+7}=8.$$
Now "add" to the original equation, divide by $2$. We get $\sqrt{x+39}=6$, and now it's over.

**Remark:** In the original post, the first step used was to square. This to some degree complicates things, the middle term should have been $-2\sqrt{(x+39)(x+7)}$. Rearrangement and squaring now get us to where we want.

Comment: Wicked method! I wouldn't have thought to invert and rationalise.

Comment: Nice result! If we "subtract" the original equation and divide the result by 2, we get $\sqrt{x+7}=2$.

Comment: Yes, I wondered about writing it up that way, the numbers are smaller. But subtraction is "more complicated" than addition.

Answer (score 4):

$$
\sqrt{x + 39} - \sqrt{x + 7} = 4 \quad \Rightarrow \quad (\sqrt{x + 39})^2 = (\sqrt{x + 7} + 4)^2 \quad \Rightarrow 
$$
$$
x + 39 = x + 7 + 8\sqrt{x + 7} + 16 \quad \Rightarrow \quad 8\sqrt{x + 7} = 16 \quad \Rightarrow \quad x = -3
$$

Comment: This method is better than direct squaring of the original equation.