# How many different solutions for this

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$\sqrt{3x^2 + 2x + 5} + \sqrt{x^2-4x+5} = \sqrt{2x^2 - 2x + 2} + \sqrt{2x^2+8}$

My attempt :

All the equation inside sqrt has $D<0$.
Let it be
$\sqrt A + \sqrt B = \sqrt C + \sqrt D$

2 possibilities
$$\sqrt A = \sqrt C \cap \sqrt B = \sqrt D$$
Find $x$ that match this condition. 
$\sqrt A = \sqrt C $ i get $x=-3 \cup x=-5$
$\sqrt B = \sqrt D $ i get $x=-3 \cup x=-1$
$$\sqrt A = \sqrt D \cap \sqrt B = \sqrt C$$
Find $x$ that match this condition.
$\sqrt A = \sqrt D $ i get $x=-3 \cup x=1$
$\sqrt B = \sqrt C $ i get $x=-3 \cup x=1$

2 solutions.

Another posibility
$\sqrt A + \sqrt B = \sqrt C + \sqrt D$
${[\sqrt A + \sqrt B]}^2 = {[\sqrt C + \sqrt D]}^2$
This part is complicated.

Is there easier way to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a=\sqrt{3x^2+2x+5}, b=\sqrt{2x^2+8}, c=\sqrt{2x^2-2x+2}, d=\sqrt{x^2-4x+5}$

$\implies a-b=c-d$

Observe that $$3x^2+2x+5-(2x^2+8)=x^2+2x-3=2x^2-2x+2-(x^2-4x+5)$$

$\implies a^2-b^2=c^2-d^2$

$\implies a+b=\dfrac{c-d}{a-b}\cdot c+d=c+d$

Now add and subtract to find $$a=c$$

$$\implies\sqrt{3x^2+2x+5}=\sqrt{2x^2-2x+2}$$

Square both sides

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/400403/solve-sqrtx4-sqrtx1-1-for-x

Comment: Ok i will try first

Comment: Observe that $$3x^2+2x+5-(2x^2+8)=2x^2-2x+2-(x^2-4x+5)$$
 Where root gone?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter, Have you noticed where we have reached ? The  solution of $$a=c\iff b=d$$  should give you the solutions

Comment: I dont get it..

Comment: @Lifeforbetter, Please find the updated post

Comment: So, $\sqrt a + \sqrt b = \sqrt c + \sqrt d$ we can just square each of them into $a + b = c + d$ ?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter, $$(\sqrt a+\sqrt b)^2=????$$

Comment: So, the answer is -3, -5? When a = c

Comment: How to be smart at math like you? Is there recipe for me?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter, there are many smarter people at math here! Please practise and follow http://google.com/search?client=ms-android-motorola-rev2&sxsrf=ACYBGNTcBWNmw_6OCP02ZIHpQD6CKWoH9Q%3A1580397084656&ei=HPIyXojUJ8HH4-EPnsCAuAQ&q=hall+knight+archive.org